# DataGridView Item Source as DataSet Works fine but want to bind columns

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, data-binding, datagridview

Currently if I set a DataGridView's ItemSource as my DataSet, it works fine:

```
    <DataGrid IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DS.Tables[0]}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}"></DataGrid>
```

However, I'm looking to set the columns manually and have their data binded to the columns in the dataset table e.g.:

```
            <DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" ItemsSource="{Binding DS.Tables[0]}" SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedItem}">
        <DataGrid.Columns>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" Binding=""/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 2" Binding=""/>
            <DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 3" Binding=""/>
        </DataGrid.Columns>
    </DataGrid>
```

I've tried multiple attempts at setting the binding for the columns but I keep resulting in an empty table when I do it this way. Would anyone know how to achieve this?

Comment: convert your datatable to an entity, and then bind it, look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33515743/5605739)

Comment: If `Binding=""` was your best attempt, what were the others?

Comment: Left Binding blank as generic. Tried multiple attempts to make it work. Your answer worked so will mark as accepted when SO lets me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[It's just a binding](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagridboundcolumn.binding(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" Binding="{Binding NameOfColumn}" />
```

I should probably mention that `NameOfColumn` should be replaced with the actual name of the first column in your table. For example, if the first column is called "FirstName", you would replace `NameOfColumn` with `FirstName`, like so:

```
<DataGridTextColumn Header="Col 1" Binding="{Binding FirstName}" />
```